# How can I prevent a slider from messing up my layout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I try to add a `Slider` to the bottom of my app, the whole `BottomAppBar` moves up to the center and the body content ("Test") is gone, as seen in the screenshots:
[image: Without Slider]
[image: With Slider]
How can I add a slider next to the two icons without destroying the whole layout?
Here's my code:

```
runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Test"),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Slider(
                value: 1,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.photo_size_select_actual),
                onPressed: () => {},
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                onPressed: () => {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: What do you mean by destruction? What happens exactly ?

Comment: The BottomAppBar is not at the bottom anymore...that's "destruction" to me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IntrinsicHeight`. This will allow it to use the exact height needed and not more.

```
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(...),
    ),
  )
```

which gives us
[image: sample]

Comment: Thx, I chose your answer because it's the simplest I think!

Answer (score 1):

i figured this out, the problem is slider takes the whole screen height and expands the BAB's height, I ran a quick solution by parenting the slider with a container and setting a height to it but I believe there are better ways.just to show you this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 60.0,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Slider(
            onChanged: (d) {
              setState(() {
                print(d);
              });
            },
            value: 1,
          ),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.photo_size_select_actual),
          onPressed: () => {},
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
          onPressed: () => {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

and the outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) Documentation

> By default, a slider will be as wide as possible, centered vertically. When given unbounded constraints, it will attempt to make the track 144 pixels wide (with margins on each side) and will shrink-wrap vertically.

So that's why always the Row and the whole BottomAppBar moves up to the center.

But you can fix this using the `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` (default to double = 56.0, you can find it in `constants.dart` file) which is flutters constant to get the height of the bottom navigation bar.Then you can wrap the row with SizedBox or Container

```
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: SizedBox(
      height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
      child: Row( ...
```